# php json_decode can't get to object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a field in a json object I am trying to do a pattern match for but I cannot seem to reach the second layer of the object.

JSON:

```
{
    "1680488": {
        "SUBID": "1680488",
        "os": "FreeBSD 10 x64",
        "ram": "2048 MB",
        "disk": "Virtual 40 GB",
        "main_ip": "107.191.60.48",
        "vcpu_count": "2",
        "location": "Tokyo",
        "DCID": "25",
        "default_password": "4",
        "date_created": "2015-02-06 02:27:22",
        "pending_charges": 7.61,
        "status": "active",
        "cost_per_month": "18.00",
        "current_bandwidth_gb": 2.706,
        "allowed_bandwidth_gb": "600",
        "netmask_v4": "255.255.254.0",
        "gateway_v4": "107.191.60.1",
        "power_status": "running",
        "VPSPLANID": "8",
        "v6_network": "2001:19f0:7000:8945::",
        "v6_main_ip": "2001:19f0:7000:8945::64",
        "v6_network_size": "64",
        "label": "Freetoo",
        "internal_ip": "",
        "kvm_url": "https://my.vultr.com/subs/vps/novnc/api.php?data=",
        "auto_backups": "yes"
    },
    "1685960": {
        "SUBID": "1685960",
        "os": "FreeBSD 10 x64",
        "ram": "768 MB",
        "disk": "Virtual 15 GB",
        "main_ip": "108.61.190.64",
        "vcpu_count": "1",
        "location": "Frankfurt",
        "DCID": "9",
        "default_password": "1",
        "date_created": "2015-02-09 00:22:42",
        "pending_charges": 2.54,
        "status": "active",
        "cost_per_month": "6.00",
        "current_bandwidth_gb": 0.612,
        "allowed_bandwidth_gb": "1000",
        "netmask_v4": "255.255.255.0",
        "gateway_v4": "108.61.190.1",
        "power_status": "running",
        "VPSPLANID": "29",
        "v6_network": "2001:19f0:6c00:8141::",
        "v6_main_ip": "2001:19f0:6c00:8141::64",
        "v6_network_size": "64",
        "label": "",
        "internal_ip": "",
        "kvm_url": "https://my.vultr.com/subs/vps/novnc/api.php?data=",
        "auto_backups": "yes"
    },
    "1694100": {
        "SUBID": "1694100",
        "os": "FreeBSD 10 x64",
        "ram": "768 MB",
        "disk": "Virtual 15 GB",
        "main_ip": "108.61.175.20",
        "vcpu_count": "1",
        "location": "London",
        "DCID": "8",
        "default_password": "9",
        "date_created": "2015-02-12 13:21:33",
        "pending_charges": 2.54,
        "status": "active",
        "cost_per_month": "6.00",
        "current_bandwidth_gb": 1.51,
        "allowed_bandwidth_gb": "1000",
        "netmask_v4": "255.255.255.0",
        "gateway_v4": "108.61.175.1",
        "power_status": "running",
        "VPSPLANID": "29",
        "v6_network": "2001:19f0:7400:84c6::",
        "v6_main_ip": "2001:19f0:7400:84c6::64",
        "v6_network_size": "64",
        "label": "",
        "internal_ip": "",
        "kvm_url": "https://my.vultr.com/subs/vps/novnc/api.php?data=",
        "auto_backups": "yes"
    },
    "1847630": {
        "SUBID": "1847630",
        "os": "FreeBSD 10 x64",
        "ram": "768 MB",
        "disk": "Virtual 15 GB",
        "main_ip": "108.61.169.203",
        "vcpu_count": "1",
        "location": "Sydney",
        "DCID": "19",
        "default_password": "ye!5",
        "date_created": "2015-04-12 05:57:47",
        "pending_charges": 0.11,
        "status": "active",
        "cost_per_month": "5.00",
        "current_bandwidth_gb": 2.43,
        "allowed_bandwidth_gb": "200",
        "netmask_v4": "255.255.254.0",
        "gateway_v4": "108.61.168.1",
        "power_status": "stopped",
        "VPSPLANID": "31",
        "v6_network": "2001:19f0:5800:8561::",
        "v6_main_ip": "2001:19f0:5800:8561::64",
        "v6_network_size": "64",
        "label": "sydney temp",
        "internal_ip": "",
        "kvm_url": "https://my.vultr.com/subs/vps/novnc/api.php?data=",
        "auto_backups": "no"
    }
}
```

Code:

```
function getlist(){
    $list_output = file_get_contents('https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/list?api_key=UY');
    return $list_output;
}

//var_dump($server_output);

echo '<br><br><br><br>';
$output = getlist();
$decoded = json_decode($output, true);
//var_dump($decoded);

foreach ($decoded as $value) {
    //echo $value['SUBID'];
    foreach ($value['SUBID'] as $piece) {
        echo '<br>';
        //var_dump($value);
        echo $piece;
    }
}
```

but any attempt to reach that second layer array fails with;

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/comm/www/mkdomain/vultr-mkvps.php on line 14
```

or similar.

How do I access the field 'labels' n the json viewer above and pattern match for Freetoo?
That is the exact object I am trying to reach.

Comment: Can you paste an example of the json data?

Comment: @Bankzilla  it's posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once inside the `foreach` there is no more depth to iterate, its just strings after that ([based on the dump](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/c95286)), its not iterable anymore, so that `foreach` inside is useless. Just access the strings indices and make your desired condition:

```
foreach($decoded as $value) {
    $id = $value['SUBID']; // string not array
    $label = $value['label']; // string
    if($label === 'Freetoo') {
        // do something
        echo $id; // and others that you have to do
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eMkwM8)

If you're insistent of having another superfluous `foreach` inside, point to the current batch array, not the string.

```
foreach($decoded as $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $piece) { // point to `$value` the array, not `$value['SUBID']` (string)
        if($key === 'label' && $piece === 'Freetoo') {
            echo $value['SUBID'];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: did I mess that up by setting json_decode($var, true)? the 'true'?  I am testing the code now.

Comment: @mine its not about that `true` flag, regardless if its accessing objects properties or array indices, the second foreach is not needed, there's nothing to iterate anymore, `$value` is just a collection of strings, there's nothing to traverse anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is you want..[sample code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RWm7Sd)

```
$output = json_decode($jsoninput,true);
foreach($output as $subid=>$row){
     echo $subid;   
     foreach ($row as $piece) {
                echo '<br>';
                //var_dump($row);
                echo $piece;
     }
}
```